# How can I extract the body of this article?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How can I only get the text the pertains to the article only? I don't want the random stuff.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

test1 = 'https://www.sfchronicle.com/news/bayarea/heatherknight/article/Special-education-teacher-a-prime-example-of-13560483.php'

# Opening up the connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(test1)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# HTML parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
#print(page_soup.prettify())

# text of article
text = page_soup.find_all('p')
print(text)
```

Comment: You could try `print(''.join([t.text for t in text]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to loop through page_soup.find_all('p').

```
     for p in page_soup.find_all('p'):
          print (p.text, p.next_sibling)
```

Comment: Is there an approach where I could remove irrelevant 'p' that would work for most articles? How would I be able to do something similar to (p.next_sibling - 1) too if I don't want the last 'p'?

Comment: If you don't want the last 'p', you could modify to ' for p in page_soup.find_all('p')[:-1]:'